# python string list to list ast.listeral_eval

Tags: python

```
>>> import ast
>>> string = '[Small, Medium, Large, X-Large]'
>>> print string
[Small, Medium, Large, X-Large]
>>> string = ast.literal_eval(string)
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
         string = ast.literal_eval(string)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
        return _convert(node_or_string)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 60, in _convert
        return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

How to fix?

Comment: @RafałRawicki I think he showed what he tried, right?

Answer (score 16):

[`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) only accepts strings which contain valid Python literal structures (strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`).

This is a valid Python expression containing only those literal structures:

```
["Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large"]
```

This isn't:

```
[Small, Medium, Large, X-Large]
```

Two ways to create a string that works:

```
string = '["Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large"]'
string = "['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'X-Large']"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your string isn't a valid list. If it's a list of strings, you need quotes.

E.g:

```
string = '["Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your have **many not-quoted strings** inside your sting list, you can do this:

```py
string = '[Small, Medium, Large, X-Large]'

[s.strip() for s in string[1:-1].split(',')]
```

which prints this:

```bash
['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'X-Large']
```

However, if you have **lots of numbers** in your string list and **just a few strings**, you can use `eval` and its `globals` parameter:

```py
mixed_string = '[1, +2, X,0  , - 4, XX, 11.2]'

eval(mixed_string, {'X': 'X', 'XX': 'XX'})
```

which prints this:

```bash
[1, 2, 'X', 0, -4, 'XX', 11.2]
```

To have all list items as stings:

```py
[str(s) for s in eval(mixed_string, {'X': 'X', 'XX': 'XX'})]
```

which prints this:

```bash
['1', '2', 'X', '0', '-4', 'XX', '11.2']
```