# How to convert string to list inside of list?

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I don't know how to convert string to list inside of list. Split method  seems the most popular, but it doesn't work.

I have a list:

```
corpus = ['[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]']
```

I want to convert string to list like that:

```
corpus = [[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]]
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python string list to list ast.listeral\_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113270/python-string-list-to-list-ast-listeral-eval)

Comment: What is *slit method*?  What makes you say it "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), a [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/967621) alternative to [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
import ast
corpus = ['[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]']
corpus = [ast.literal_eval(item) for item in corpus]
print(corpus)
# [[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this simple code will help.

```
import re

corpus = ['[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]']
corpus[0] = re.findall(r'\(\d, \d\)', corpus[0])
temp_lst1 = []

for i in corpus[0]:
    temp_lst2 = []
    for j in i:
        try:
            if type(int(j)) == int:
                temp_lst2.append(int(j))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    temp_lst1.append(tuple(temp_lst2))

corpus[0] = temp_lst1

print(corpus)
```